# Set-ciminstance failing in powershell script task sequence

Tags: powershell, task, sequence, sccm

Running a server build task sequence in SCCM and encountering the following error when a configuration script runs to assign a different drive letter to one of the drives.

The command being ran from the script.

```
$LocalDataDrive = "E"
$dataDrive = Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemLabel -eq "Data"}
if($dataDrive){
    Write-Output "    DEBUG: Change Data drive letter to: $LocalDataDrive"
    $dataDriveLetter = $dataDrive.DriveLetter
    Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '${dataDriveLetter}:'" | Set-CimInstance -Arguments @{DriveLetter="${LocalDataDrive}:"
}
```

Verified running the script manually on the server does assign the correct drive letter.

The error being logged:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Set-CimInstance): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Not supported "
>> TerminatingError(Set-CimInstance): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Not supported "
>> TerminatingError(Set-CimInstance): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Not supported "
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Not supported
Set-CimInstance : Not supported
At D:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\A01002CB\HPE-New-StoreHost.ps1:111 char:89
+ ... etter}:'" | Set-CimInstance -Arguments @{DriveLetter="${LocalDataDriv ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (Win32_Volume: D...4-adba-0529...):CimInstance) [Set-CimInstance], CimEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100c,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.SetCimInstanceCommand
PS>$global:?
False
```

This same task previously worked on the same servers (HPE ML110s in RAID config).
The same task still does work on our older Lenovo servers.

Verified running the script manually on the server does assign the correct drive letter.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace. So, it works on older gen servers? You may want to post the more info on the error using `$Error`.

Comment: `Set-CimInstance -Property @{DriveLetter="${LocalDataDrive}:"}`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala sorry that was an error pulling over only the relevant parts of the script . 
Yes, it works on older Lenovos running 2012R2  

These new ones are either 2019 or 2022. I have been able to build them successfully before, so not sure why running the builds again is failing. 

I have tried removing the raid array completely, rebuilding the array,  but still errors. To add more confusion, sometimes there is no error in the log. The last line is just the write-output line in the script and nothing else.